# Superagent: Error: Parser is unable to parse the response

Tags: json, ajax, reactjs, superagent, ipfs

I'm using [Superagent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent) in my react app, and i'm making some call's to the [IPFS](https://ipfs.io/docs/api/) api. Specifically, I am uploading files to my IPFS server. Now, everything works, When I upload one or multiple files the call goes through and the files show up in IPFS no problem.

A problem occurs when I upload multiple files though, the response seems to come back as plain text, instead of JSON, and superagent throws the error

```
client.js:399 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Parser is unable to parse the response
    at Request.<anonymous> (client.js:399)
    at Request.Emitter.emit (index.js:133)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (client.js:708)
```

So to be clear, when uploading a single file, I get a nice JSON response, but when I upload multiple files, the response is in plain text.

Can I force Superagent to give me the response back and parse it myself? Or can I set something when making the call so that it forces a json parse? Below is my superagent request function

```
  add : acceptedFiles => {
    const url = ipfs.getUrl("add")
    const req = request.post(url)

    acceptedFiles.forEach(file => req.attach(file.name, file))

    req.then(res => {
      return console.log(res);
    })
  }
```

Comment: did you find the answer to this question? I am experiencing the same difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

I'm searching for this for a more elegant solution, but before I would have found it , I'd like to provide my own solution.

---

I think this problem caused by wrong responsive `Content-Type` set, but I've not confirmed this opinion yet.

However, you can try this:

```js
req.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err.rawResponse)
})
```

At least, this solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to [their docs](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#parsing-response-bodies) you can specify custom parser that will take precedence over built-in parser:

> You can set a custom parser (that takes precedence over built-in parsers) with the `.buffer(true).parse(fn)` method. If response buffering is not enabled (`.buffer(false)`) then the response event will be emitted without waiting for the body parser to finish, so response.body won't be available.

I tried and it worked well for me.

```
superagent.get('....')
    .buffer(true)
    .parse(({ text }) => JSON.parse(text))
    .then(...)
```

Comment: the parse worked for me, thank you very much